# Read RFID tag via nodejs

Tags: node.js, rfid

Hello I have bought RFID reader with antenna(FX7500). Now trying to read tag through nodejs LLRP implementation from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/llrp 
. My intention is to make an application as like SessionOne with nodejs. Can anybody guide me on where to start? I am a bit stuck now. thanks in advance

Comment: where are you stuck? what did you try so far?

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried with the code provided by the nodejs module. 'use strict';

var llrp = require('./index.js');

var reader = new llrp({
 ipaddress: '192.168.0.100'
});

reader.connect();

reader.on('timeout', function () {
 console.log('timeout');
});

reader.on('disconnect', function () {
 console.log('disconnect');
});

reader.on('error', function (error) {
 console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});

reader.on('didSeeTag', function (tag) {
 console.log('TAG: ' + tag.tagID);
});

Comment: ok, and what is the problem?

Comment: at last i can see the tag after running nodejs module. But the tag is scanning continuously non-stop. How can i make it just stop after found once. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello my friends, suddenly the nodejs dont show any tag . just keep waiting and waiting and timeout. Any clue why it's happenning ?